# How to recuperate a hidden field at Orbeon in mode dev (Java)

Tags: java, xml, visibility, orbeon

I have a hidden field 'X'. I want to get the value of this field when I implement a method in Java. First I got the form as XML content. Second I will get the value of this field 'X'. But when I execute the method, the field `X` in XML didn't exist.

Comment: i tried to write in thech visibility `not($fr-mode='new' and $fr-mode'edit' )` but also didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us more about from where the Java code you want to access the XML instance from is called? And in that code, how are you retrieving the XML instance?

Comment: If you have the form *data* in XML format, then a Form Runner/Form Builder field name "foo" will be available as XML element `<foo>`. If you parse the XML then you can navigate the XML tree to find that element.

Comment: but when this field in builder is invisible so in xml he is filled